# InvalidClientTokenId when creating IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am trying to create the following IAM Role with a Policy. The Role is attached to a Lambda.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
    function_name = "test"

    s3_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.deployment_bucket.id}"
    s3_key = "${var.deployment_key}"

    handler = "${var.function_handler}"
    runtime = "${var.lambda_runtimes[var.desired_runtime]}"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
    name = "test-role"

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_policy" {
    name = test-policy"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
            "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
            "xray:PutTraceSegments",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

I run `terraform apply` from an EC2 instance that has an IAM Role attached to it. The IAM Role has the AdministratorAccess and can deploy VPCs and EC2s with Terraform without any issue. When I try to create the IAM Role and Policy above though it fails with `InvalidClientTokenId` error.

> - aws_iam_role.lambda_role: Error creating IAM Role test-role: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

I then generated a set of access key credentials and hard-coded them and it still failed. Is there something special I need to do when creating an IAM Role? Any other `terraform apply` commands I run from this machine work fine until I need to create an IAM Role.

Comment: Did you specify the aws provider:     provider "aws" {
      region  = "us-east-2"
    } and did you setup your aws credentials

Comment: Yeah, the provider region is set and as I mentioned, I’ve used both the EC2 IAM role and tried hard-coded access key and secret key in the provider config. Everything can be provisioned without any issue, except IAM Roles. I can provision subnets, VPCs, EC2s, S3 buckets etc without issue. I can’t provision an IAM Role.

Comment: The credentials used have the AdministratorAccess policy assigned and IAMFullAccess policy assigned.